# How to Install Standard Libraries in Python Virtual Environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-venv

When I work on a Python Virtual Environment ([`$ python -m venv myenv`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/venv.html)), I couldn't find the `os` module in it.

I tried `$ pip install os`, but couldn't find the package there as well. How do I go about installing modules from the standard library?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to import the module? If not, it sounds like your Python installation is broken. The standard library has its name because it is always included in a vanilla Python installation.

Comment: I'm able to import, but PyCharm hints it as from the system environment rather than the virtual environment. I am not too sure if it would work when I move it to another machine.

Comment: I am guessing that you are using the same Python version in your venv as your system version? Then it could just be that the standard library is called from the system version because it is always there. If your venv version is different from the system version, that would be weird.

Comment: Yes, the versions are the same. Does it mean that the IDE is just picking up the system path for hint display?

Comment: Yes. virtualenv uses the system Python’s standard library but contains its own copy of the Python interpreter. The standard library gets symlinked in your venv folder. My guess is that your IDE just resolves that link.

Answer (score 2):

OS module is usually included in the standard Python installation and you can't really install it with pip.

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/index.html